# Simplifying Equation - Asymptotic analysis

Tags: asymptotics

The textbook I'm using for the course Introduction to Algorithms class has the following statement in it:

> The equation of such a line is
>
> $\log (T(N)) = 3 \log N + \log a$
>
> (where a is a constant) which is equivalent to
>
> $T(N) = a N^{3}$

My rusty algebra just cannot get me from the first one to the second one. My last math class, a graduate level intro to stats class, was twenty years ago.

Can someone walk me through how they got from the first equation to the second equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to remember, that
\begin{align}
\log(a)+\log(b) = \log(a\cdot b)
\end{align}
And secondly
\begin{align}
c\cdot\log(a)=\log(a^c)
\end{align}
From that follows that
\begin{align}
3\log(N)+\log(a) = \log(N^3)+\log(a) = \log(aN^3)= \log(T(n))
\end{align}
So $T(n) = aN^3$.

Note: This holds for $\log, \quad\log_{10}, \quad  \log_x$ or whatever you take as your basis.

Comment: Okay, that helps. Thank you very much. (I'm sorry I can't upvote yet.)